# Probability at least one spade and card higher than a 7

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

There is a 52 card deck and you are dealt 13 cards.

**Question:** What is the probability neither of the following cases happen: no spades and no card higher than 7

Thus that means you get at least one spade and the card is higher than 7. I'm not sure if it's **and** or **or** with that wording though.

I understand that the $P(\text{at least one spade}) = 1 - P(\text{no spades})$.

$$P(\text{no spades}) = \frac{\binom{39}{13}}{\binom{52}{13}}$$

But how do I factor in the second requirement of the card being higher than a 7?

Comment: You only have $6$ cards higher than $7$ that are spades. You have $8,9,10,jack,queen,king$.

Comment: @Numbermind I don't think the high card had to be a spade.

Comment: @Numbermind So I can look at it as 1 - P(No spades and card above 7)? I just wasn't sure if I could add that second part in since I made it 1 - P(no spades)? So would it be 1 - (28 choose 13)? Because there are 6 cards lower than 7, and 4 suits of each so 6*4 = 24. Then (52-24 choose 13)?

Comment: @RobertZ the actual question is what is the probability neither of the following cases happen: no spades and no card higher than 7

Comment: So... everyone here assumes an ace is lower than a seven?  It doesn't change the principal, but questions like this *should* clarify that, as games where an ace is considered lower than a two are exceptionally rare compared to games where an ace is higher than a king.

Comment: All the answers, including mine, are wrong.  The probability is that no spade and no card higher than 7 *not* happening.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

No cards greater than 7 would include 2,3,4,5,6 and 7.  There are 4 suits Thus (6*4) = 24.  Subtract 6 spades because it is no spades too.  Thus you have 24-6 = 18 cards.These are the outcomes that should not happen and the complement is the required probabiity.  Thus the required probability =$1-\dfrac{{18\choose 13}}{{52\choose 13}}$

Comment: I don't want to remove spades from the sets, because I need to choose at least one spade

Comment: No, you don't.  You need to choose one spade OR one card higher than 7.  This tells you the prob of doing *NEITHER*.  So the prob of doing at least $1$ is $1 - this$.

Comment: Neither is the catch

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be easier to *not* separate into two events.

There are $18$ "good" cards, the $2-7$ of diamonds, clubs, and hearts and $32$ bad cards, everything else.

So there are $18 \choose 13$ positive outcomes for this to happens and $52 \choose 13$ total outcomes.

So $P$ is $\frac {18 \choose 13}{52 \choose 13}=\frac {18!39!}{52!5!} $

It's probably straightforward to combine the probabilities of no spades, and lower than $7$ but.... why bother?

So $1 - \frac {18 \choose 13}{52 \choose 13}$

[This assumes an ace is higher than a king and a two is the lowest rank.]

====

If you want to consider the events as two events (but I strongly urge you *don't*)

P(nothing higher than seven and no spaces)= P(nothing higher than seven| no spades)P(no spades) = P(no spades|nothing higher than seven)P(nothing higher than seven)

P(nothing higher than seven| no spades)=$\frac{18\choose 13}{39\choose 13}$

P(no spades) = $\frac {39\choose 13}{52 \choose 13}$

P(no spades|nothing higher than seven)=$\frac{18\choose 13}{24 \choose 13}$

P(nothing higher than seven) = $\frac {24\choose 13}{52\choose 13}$

Clearly these three different ways will all give the same result.